# if you are fired on an E3 visa does the employer pay for cost of transport home?

Tags: usa, visa, employment, paperwork, foreign-employment

If fired on an E3 visa is the employer liable for paying the reasonable cost of transport home? I know this is the case for H1B visas. Is this also true for E3 visas? Is there any legislation someone can point me to?

Comment: Is this true for H1B? I would have thought your employee contract would state the company liabilities not the type of VISA? Interested in this myself to know from people with experience

Comment: Pretty sure that for H1B this is set out by the USCIS. Their website explicitly says that the employer is responsible for return transport. However, I can't find anything for E3.

Comment: @MattDouhan This is covered in INA 214(c)(5)(A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule that you are referring to is covered under [INA 214(c)(5)(A)](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid%3AUSC-prelim-title8-section1184&num=0&edition=prelim) which states:

> In the case of an alien who is provided nonimmigrant status under
>   section 1101(a)(15)(H)(i)(b) or 1101(a)(15)(H)(ii)(b) of this title
>   and who is dismissed from employment by the employer before the end of
>   the period of authorized admission, the employer shall be liable for
>   the reasonable costs of return transportation of the alien abroad.

Given that this is specifically with regards to H-1B and H-2B visas, it does not appear that E-3 visas would be covered under this provision.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matt, I'm aware of the rule sections you cited. I was not able to trace whether they specifically applied only to H1B/H2B visas or included E3 as well. Do those documents exclude E3? I was confused because the E3 is very similar to the H1B and numerous unofficial websites have said that the employer is responsible.

Comment: @choc_chips 1101(a)(15)(H)(i)(b) and 1101(a)(15)(H)(ii)(b) ARE the H-1B and H-2B visas. So no, those explicitly do not include the E-3 visa. I have not found any other law that would require this for an E-3 worker.